# MySQL Join on function? Can this be improved?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

So, taking a look at some queries for Concrete5 and attempting to do some indexing on their tables. I came across one query that I thought "There has got to be a better way" but my research hasn't led me anywhere. Specefically, my question is: "Is it possible to write the `if(p2.cID IS NULL, p1.cID, p2.cID)` section of the inner join." I have to believe that this causes some inefficiency for the joins, I've attached the query explain output in hopes that someone else could tell me if it really even matters. Right now this is a fresh install so not much data, but using a function in an inner join just seems... well odd to me.

[image: Join of Ifs Explain]

And the query:

```
select p1.cID, pt.ptHandle, c.cDateAdded, pagepaths.cPath 
from Pages p1 left join Pages p2 on (p1.cPointerID = p2.cID) 
left join PagePaths on (PagePaths.cID = p1.cID and PagePaths.ppIsCanonical = 1) 
left join PageSearchIndex psi on (psi.cID = if(p2.cID is null, p1.cID, p2.cID)) 
inner join CollectionVersions cv on (cv.cID = if(p2.cID is null, p1.cID, p2.cID) and cvID = 1) 
left join PageTypes pt on (pt.ptID = if(p2.cID is null, p1.ptID, p2.ptID)) 
inner join Collections c on (c.cID = if(p2.cID is null, p1.cID, p2.cID));
```

Query Execution Time for If Query with no cache: 0.00161268

Notice all the joins that are using the if function. I was able to get the same query results via a union query, but I'm honestly not sure doing that is any more efficient. Also keep in mind that using PHP a where clause is dynamically added, but I'm less concerned about that right now. I'd be open to suggestions on how this could be improved or if most people would say that this would scale just fine.

**UPDATE**

Here is the Union Query (which runs considerably slower with a small result set) and Explain:

[image: Union Query Explain]

```
select p1.cID, pt.ptHandle, c.cDateAdded, pagepaths.cPath 
from Pages p1 left join Pages p2 on (p1.cPointerID = p2.cID) 
left join PagePaths on (PagePaths.cID = p1.cID and PagePaths.ppIsCanonical = 1) 
left join PageSearchIndex psi on (psi.cID = p1.cID AND p2.cID is null) 
inner join CollectionVersions cv on (cv.cID = p1.cID AND p2.cID is null and cvID = 1) 
left join PageTypes pt on (pt.ptID = p1.ptID AND p2.cID is null) 
inner join Collections c on (c.cID = p1.cID AND p2.cID is null)
UNION
select p1.cID, pt.ptHandle, c.cDateAdded, pagepaths.cPath 
from Pages p1 left join Pages p2 on (p1.cPointerID = p2.cID) 
left join PagePaths on (PagePaths.cID = p1.cID and PagePaths.ppIsCanonical = 1) 
left join PageSearchIndex psi on (psi.cID = p2.cID AND p2.cID is not null) 
inner join CollectionVersions cv on (cv.cID = p2.cID AND p2.cID is not null and cvID = 1) 
left join PageTypes pt on (pt.ptID = p2.ptID AND p2.cID is not null) 
inner join Collections c on (c.cID = p2.cID AND p2.cID is not null);
```

Query Execution Time for Union Query with no cache: 0.00763072

**UPDATE 2 (Barmar's Subquery Version)**

So this doesn't seem to perform to much differently than the current one using IF's, but it does come up with a different query execution plan.

[image: Subquery Explain]

Query:

```
SELECT p.cID, pt.ptHandle, c.cDateAdded, pp.cPath
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(p2.cID, p1.cID) as cID, IFNULL(p2.ptID, p1.ptID) AS ptID
      FROM Pages AS p1
      LEFT JOIN Pages AS p2 ON (p1.cPointerID = p2.cID)) AS p
left join PagePaths pp on (pp.cID = p.cID AND pp.ppIsCanonical = 1)
left join PageSearchIndex psi on (psi.cID = p.cID) 
inner join CollectionVersions cv on (cv.cID = p.cID and cvID = 1) 
left join PageTypes pt on (pt.ptID = p.ptID) 
inner join Collections c on (c.cID = p.cID);
```

Query Execution Time for Subquery version with no cache: 0.00190587

Comment: The UNION might be best. Another option is to join with a subquery that returns `p1.cID, p1.ptID` or `p2.cID, p2.ptID` depending on `p2.cID`.

Comment: The union query seems to be a no go, see updated question

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use IF(... IS NULL, ...) instead of ISNULL or better yet, COALESCE, like `on (psi.cID = COALESCE(p2.cID, p1.cID))`?

Comment: @JosephB nope, that's just the way the query was written but I imagine the query execution plan would be extremely similar from a join perspective and performance perspective my just switching those out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version that joins with a subquery that returns the appropriate IDs:

```
SELECT p.cID, p2.ptHandle, c.cDateAdded, pp.cPath
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(p2.cID, p1.cID) as cID, IFNULL(p2.ptID, p1.ptID) AS ptID
      FROM Pages AS p1
      LEFT JOIN Pages AS p2 ON (p1.cPointerID = p2.cID)) AS p
left join PagePaths pp on (PagePaths.cID = p.cID AND pp.ppIsCanonical = 1)
left join PageSearchIndex psi on (psi.cID = p.cID) 
inner join CollectionVersions cv on (cv.cID = p.cID and cvID = 1) 
left join PageTypes pt on (pt.ptID = p.ptID) 
inner join Collections c on (c.cID = p.cID);
```

Comment: This does indeed accomplish it in another way. I've updated my question to include the statistics and explain on your subquery. Unfortunately for my small result set it was actually a hair slower, I'll have to dummy up some data to test with a bit later and see how it compares.